# Is it appropriate to defend a question that demonstrates no effort to solve the problem?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'll begin straight with an example.  In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650489/what-does-return-do) post, it's asked what `return` does in Perl.  Fair enough, thus far.

Within a minute, someone commented:

> I guess search is a bless to only the few selected. [The very first result of google leads you to the perl website answer to it](https://www.google.com/#q=perl+return)

It seemed to me that there was nothing offensive in the comment.  *It stated the fact that simply supplying the two words to a search engine would answer the question.*  However, it seems that folks ([an example](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8454/andy-lester)) who have been around on SO for a while, seem to think that making such a comment is [insulting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650489/what-does-return-do#comment27462508_18650489).

While I agree that one shouldn't be rude or insulting (which certainly didn't seem so in this example), shouldn't we attempt to encourage users to exercise some bit of effort on their part rather than criticising those who attempt to do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Andy Lester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8454/andy-lester) nailed it:

> "I guess search is a bless to only the few selected" is insultingly sarcastic and unnecessary.

The first sentence of the comment you quoted is rather heavily sarcastic. The entire thing reads like "Gosh, you just don't know how to search. But I do."

That comment is little more than a "let me google that for you" link which we block outright because, well, in the vast majority of cases, people linking to LMGTFY aren't doing it to be nice.

Now, certainly, the question *is* basic. And it *is* answerable with a simple search or by picking up literally<sup>1</sup> any book about Perl. However, the same amount of effort that went into putting that snide comment together could've gone into typing up something like ["it will end the subroutine and return the value"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650525/105971), or typing nothing at all and just downvoting and moving on<sup>2</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Probably. Your mileage may vary.</sub>
<sup>2</sup> <sub>There is a fine line between a naive question from a new developer and a too-basic question  that probably doesn't belong on SO. This specific example is likely in the latter category, but the distinction is something to keep in mind still.</sub>

Comment: If you think about the question, it is not actually so simple, the way it was asked is suggesting the OP is at the basic level of understanding, but this question could be a good place of explaining the actual meaning of the return statement.

Comment: @cerkiewny Perhaps. Regardless of the merits of the question, the comment that sparked this discussion was inappropriate and there are better ways to handle situations like this.

Comment: The last line of your answer `However, ...` makes much sense.  Thanks.